# How to append new column to csv with Python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with several columns. One column contains a list of websites in varying formats and I'm trying to parse out the domain and suffix for each of them and append to a new column.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import csv
import tldextract

parsed_domains = []
with open('output.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    # csv_writer = csv.writer('output.csv')
    for row in csv_reader:
        website_col = row[7]
        ext = tldextract.extract(website_col)
        parsed_domain = ext.domain+'.'+ext.suffix
        print(parsed_domain)
```

This script successfully prints a list of the parsed domains however I can't figure out how to append them to my existing csv.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: rather than thinking of appending (which for files adds rows, not columns) think about rewriting the file entirely.  Read it all in. Process. Write it all back out.

Comment: Pick one from [`[python] [csv] change columns`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D+%5Bcsv%5D+change+columns)